# Comparing Strings in String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

This code works perfectly for numbers but not for characters. Can someone tell me why an give me suggestions?

```
package optimum.output;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OptimumOutput {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // First of all we have to get what the runs planned for next month. To get that there should be separate method

    plannedruns();

}
//plannedruns method is ment to get next month planned runs
 static String[] plannedruns(){

    String[] runs=new String[50];      
    //Writes instructions in console
    System.out.println("Instructions"+"\n"+"Please enter Job ID's that planned for this month (Mazimum 50 jobs)"+"\n"+"At the end of the list, enter 0");
    // Scanner to take inputs
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;
    //takes job ID inputs
    for(int position=0;position<50;position++){
        System.out.print("Enter Job ID for Job " + ++i +" : ");
        runs[position]=null;
        runs[position] = scanner.nextLine();
        try{
                if (Integer.parseInt(runs[position])==0){
                break;
            }
            for(int j=0;position>j;j++){
                System.out.print(runs[j].equalsIgnoreCase(runs[position]));
                if(runs[j].equals(runs[position])){
                    System.out.println("One job repeated. Please enter the run correctly");
                    --i;
                    --position;
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){                
        }
    }
    //Print before printing job details
    System.out.println("These are the entered jobs for this month");
    i=0;
    for(int position=0;position<50;){
        try{
            if (Integer.parseInt(runs[position])==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){            
        }
        System.out.println("Job No."+ ++i +" is "
                + ""+runs[position++]);

    }
    System.out.println("end");
    return runs;
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work" please. This question is too vague to answer at the moment. If you could provide a [mcve] - ideally with hardcoded data to avoid relying on user input - it would be a lot easier to help you

Comment: Have you tried `equalsIgnoreCase`. Or better, what does "it does not work" mean in your case?

Comment: what is your code intended to do

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], and you haven't given any indication of the data that's failing, or what kind of failure you mean. The fact that you're catching exceptions without doing *anything* with them is a bad start in terms of working out what's going on.

Comment: lets's say job ID something like S20170312B13, F20170311K09, or simply a,b c d e

Comment: if(runs[j].equals(runs[position]))

Comment: it is the one that does not work for characters. but work for numbers

Comment: Use `==` for `char` rather equals .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why earlier it wasn't working. But few non related changes it is completely working.

```
static String[] plannedruns(){
         //job ID is taken as String
        String[] runs=new String[50]; 
        //Writes instructions in console
        System.out.println("Instructions"+"\n"+"Please enter Job ID's that planned for this month (Mazimum 50 jobs)"+"\n"+"At the end of the list, enter 0");
        // Scanner to take inputs
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0;
        //takes job ID inputs
        for(int position=0;position<50;position++){
            System.out.print("Enter Job ID for Job " + ++i +" : ");
            runs[position]=null;
            runs[position] = scanner.nextLine();
            try{
                    if (runs[position].equalsIgnoreCase("end")){
                        runs[position]=null;
                    break;
                }
                for(int j=0;position>j;j++){
                    //1
                    System.out.print(runs[j].equals(runs[position]));
                    if(runs[j].equals(runs[position])){
                        System.out.println("One job repeated. Please enter the run correctly");
                        --i;
                        --position;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){                
            }
        }
        //Print before printing job details
        System.out.println("These are the entered jobs for this month");
        i=0;
        for(int position=0;position<50;){
            try{
                if (runs[position]==null){
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){            
            }
            System.out.println("Job No."+ ++i +" is "
                    + ""+runs[position++]);

        }
        System.out.println("end");
        return runs;
    }
```